# Did "user" have positive or negative connotation in 1950?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, history, historical-change

Since the advent of ubiquitous technology, the meaning of "user" is best know as the person sitting in front of the computer or similar device.

I am studying the history of computing and want to question the meaning of this word choice.

I understand two connotations available with this word:

## Negative

*User* is a person that interacts with a thing. They are not able to control that thing (an *operator*). They are not the owner of that thing (an *owner*). They are not able to change that thing (a *tinkerer*). Basically, the *user* is restricted in what they can accomplish with the thing and they are powerless over it. A common phrase *drug user* also illustrates this context, drug users never compound or negotiate with drugs, they are only taking drugs and the all-powerful drugs are doing what they are doing.

In every context I can think of a more flattering word than *user*. A public transit user is a *rider*. A facebook user is a *viewer* or a *poster*, maybe even a *member*. If you are an advertiser then maybe they are *a pair of eyeballs*. A user of government services is a *recipient*. A user of a machine is an *operator*. But if a mouse is inside a maze then that mouse is a user -- the maze is utterly unaffected by the mouse and the mouse will only act inside the maze in the ways that the maze was designed for.

## Neutral / positive

A user is the receipt of services from a machine/thing. Insofar as the receipt has the power to stop at any time, we assume the recipient is being served by the machine and they are receiving value and worthwhile experience.

Or if we are more dispassionate, there is a machine and a user. We don't really care much more than that. Basically a *user* is the one that sits on the chair in front of the machine. We might as well just call them a machine sitter.

---

**Back in the 1950's before ubiquitous technology, which was the prominent connotation of the word?**

Comment: I think you need to route the path through *end-user*. *End-user* seems to have been a term coined with regards to utility customers. It referred to the entity associated with an electric meter or water meter. *User* is basically a shortening of *end-user* back to just *user*, but retaining the restricted idea of *end user*. *End user* wasn't disparaging.

Comment: The only really negative use of user is drug user as a euphemism, at times, for a drug addict. I know of no other negative user. Except in the colloquial idiom: he or she is a user. Meaning: to use other people for one's own ends.

Comment: "User" simply has too many different meanings and connotations to assign it a single "positive" or "negative" implication.

Comment: "End-user" has a special meaning. Because it is so common to talk about machines that exist for the usage by other machines which are in turned used by humans, we want to reference those humans which are N-levels deep at the end. This may sound ridiculous, but in software this is very common.

Comment: In modern usage, and having worked on software, I find "user" to be a derogatory term. It means that all your attention is spent on controlling the customer with calls-to-action and dopamine, and you didn't even bother to consider their agency, they are just bags of meat.

Answer (score 6):

## Neutral *user* during the 50s

As far as I can see, all current senses of *user* were present during the 1950s.

To demonstrate this, here from [the OED entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/220650?rskey=NGKfSr&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)<sup>(*paywalled*)</sup> for the word ***user*** is a selected excerpt of citations from that decade (plus a few from immediately before and after):

> - 1946  *Canad. Jrnl. Res.* A. 24 20   The photographic plane must be selected according to a criterion that satisfies the **user** requirement.
> - 1949  *Surv. Current Business* May 17 (caption)    The seasonally adjusted 1948 year-end annual rate of power production, including **user**-owned plants, was about 350 billion kilowatt-hours.
> - 1950  Charleston (W. Virginia) *Daily Mail* 9 Feb. 17/1   Railways support..a **user** fee for use of public facilities.
> - 1950  Greeley (Colorado) *Daily Tribune* 27 Sept. 7/5   We favor the distribution of the burden for the maintenance and construction of the various highway systems..on the basis of **user** benefit.
> - 1950  *Science* 112 732/1   Analog machines..are enthusiastically supported by their **user**s.
> - 1951  *Brit. Jrnl. Photogr. Almanac* 357   Since Ektachrome film is intended for **user** processing, the sale price does not include this service.
> - 1951  *N.Y. Times* 16 July 29 (advt.)    Both **user**ship and brand awareness fall off in a sharp, regular descent as age increases.
> - 1953  *Humboldt* (Eureka, Calif.) *Standard* 24 Mar. 5/5   Ford is rolling with a new model that has had more than a year of **user** testing and time for refinement.
> - 1953  W. S. Burroughs *Junkie* vi. 58   The owner knew Tony had been a **user** and had told him to stay off the stuff or get another job.
> - 1954  *Summary Rep.* (Amer. Library Assoc.) 38   University libraries should be student and **user**-centered rather than material-centered.
> - 1957  *Managem. Sci.* 3 208   The **user**-oriented point of view is emphasized.
> - 1959  E. M. McCormick *Digital Computer Primer* x. 139   The number of instructions which can be executed by a computer represents a compromise between the designer’s and **user**’s requirements.
> - 1960  A. Ellis *Essence of Beauty* xii. 142   The characteristic a discerning and discriminating **user** looks for in a perfume..is what the perfumer calls ‘the soft odour note’.
> - 1961  *ISA Jrnl.* Mar. 60 (heading)    Better measurements through **user** feedback.
> - 1963  *Communications ACM* 6 88/2   ‘Official’ documentation has a certain amount of difficulty to it, which is particularly apparent with **user**-generated languages such as IPL.
> - 1963  *Science* 5 July 9 (advt.)    Kodak Ektachrome-X Film..offers practical possibility for **user**-processing.

### Computer *users*

However, I can see nothing that indicates a positive or negative connotation outside the Burroughs quotation. The computing sense related to friendliness or unfriendliness did not arise until the 1980s:

> - 1981  *Economist* 16 May 55/1  The winners will be those whose machines do not bristle with difficulty and are ‘**user**-friendly’. Prestel, with its numerical codes, is, in the view of many, ‘user-unfriendly’.
> - 1994  *.net* Dec. 33/1  The Net, in general, is **user**-unfriendly.
> - 2001  F. Popcorn & A. Hanft *Dict. Future* 163  Technology that is too complex and appallingly **user**-unfriendly appears on the market.

## Negative *user* during the 70s

The disparaging connotation of *user* seems to have arisen in the decade previous to that. “This word was coined around 1975 at MIT” can be found in [*The Jargon File*’s entry for ***luser***](http://catb.org/jargon/html/L/luser.html), which reads:

> ### *luser*
>
> A ***user***; esp. one who is also a ***loser***. (*luser* and *loser* are 
>   pronounced identically.) This word was coined around 1975 at MIT. Under
>   ITS, when you first walked up to a terminal at MIT and typed Control-Z to
>   get the computer’s attention, it printed out some status information,
>   including how many people were already using the computer; it might print
>   “14 users”, for example. Someone thought it would be a great joke to patch
>   the system to print “14 losers” instead. There ensued a great controversy,
>   as some of the users didn't particularly want to be called losers to their
>   faces every time they used the computer. For a while several hackers
>   struggled covertly, each changing the message behind the back of the
>   others; any time you logged into the computer it was even money whether it
>   would say “users” or “losers”. Finally, someone tried the compromise
>   “lusers”, and it stuck.  Later one of the ITS machines supported **luser**
>   as a request-for-help command. ITS died the death in mid-1990, except as a
>   museum piece; the usage lives on, however, and the term luser is often seen
>   in program comments and on Usenet. Compare ***mundane, muggle, newbie, chainik***.

Answer (score 3):

My c.1959 *Webster's Unabridged Dictionary* gives the following definition for *user*:

> User (noun):
>
> 1. a person or thing that uses (from the primary sense of the transitive verb, *use*).
> 2. in law, (a) the exercise of a right to use; (b) a right of use, based on long use (substantively from Old French, *user*, "to use".

The verb *use* is given as:

> 1. to put or bring into action or service; to employ for or apply to a given purpose.

So, beyond the very neutral and narrow basic definitions of the terminology, it is only within the context of usage where we may be introduced to themes of morality or ethics requiring the application of judgment, whether positive or negative. Certainly, for one person to *use* another, or to use any living thing perhaps, or to overuse common resources -- might provoke negative feelings and judgments.

Answer (score -1):

LOSER has been a pejorative term for many years, long before computer people came along.

In Australia at least, a ‘user’ is someone who takes advantage of the help or generosity of others but never offers any in return.

He or she ‘uses’ them and thus is a ‘user’.

Has been so for many years, going back at least to the 1940s.